# i have sms receiver but doesnt works

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

this is an sms receiver but doesn't work!!! here are my codes . i dont know whats the problem!!!!
also i had installed gosms!!is there any problem??

my manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sms_rec"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sms_rec.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".Smsreciv"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>


            </receiver>

    </application>


    </manifest>
```

my main activity:

```
    package com.example.sms_rec;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    enter code here
    import android.os.Bundle;


     public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{


    private static final BroadcastReceiver Smsreciv = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  



       }    
}

---------------------------------
```

my sms reciver:
    ----------------------------

```
    package com.example.sms_rec;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.widget.Toast;

     public abstract class Smsreciv extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }    


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

> this is an sms receiver but doesnt work

In the future, please explain what "doesnt work" means, by providing specific symptoms.

> is there any problem?

One thing that is definitely wrong is that you have the `abstract` keyword on the class definition for `Smsreciv`. This will prevent Android from creating an instance of this class. You should be seeing a warning or error in LogCat about this. Please remove `abstract`, as you do not need it.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SMS/Monitor) demonstrates an app that can monitor SMS messages.